# including algorithms in latex

Tags: algorithms

I am using the

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

packages and creating a sample algorithm using the `\COMMENT`, `\IF`, `\ENDIF` and `\FOR` constructs. When I compile this and view the PDF file, I don't see any of the key words, the indenting is not correct and I have to explicitly mention the key words. Is there anything that I am missing here?

I am using TeXShop on OS X.

EDIT :

This is what I am using

```
       \begin{algorithm}
       \caption{Algorithm for finding server indices using OFG}

        \begin{algorithmic}
        \newline
        \COMMENT { \%comment: servers[] contains the index of servers whose         data rate are sorted in descending order\%}\newline
        \STATE servers[]= index(of all servers) \newline
        \STATE serverIndex[]=servers[0..K]\newline
        \STATE linearlyIndependentServerIndex[]=0\newline
        \STATE $[Z] \leftarrow 0$\newline
        \FOR  {$i=0$ to $serverIndex.length$} \newline
        \COMMENT{ \%comment: find the equation corresponding the serverIndex        from the mapping at the File Server\%} \newline
        \STATE        $eqn= equation(serverIndex[i])$ \newline
        \COMMENT{ \%comment: try insert equation into Z using OFG\%} \newline

         \ENDFOR end for\newline \newline
         \WHILE{ ( linearlyIndependentServerIndex.length!=K ) } \newline
          \COMMENT{\%comment: remove all the server index which were not inserted in Z\%} \newline 
         \STATE temp[]=serverIndex[]-linearlyIndependentServerIndex \newline
           \IF{  (linearlyIndependentServerIndex.length=K) }\newline
           \STATE break\newline
           \ENDIF  \newline
         \ENDWHILE  \newline
        \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
```

I had to include newline so that the code is readable.

The resulting output after compiling:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please look at the documentation of the [algorithmicx](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx) package. You used the wrong names for the keywords.

The `\newline` commands can be removed once the correct keywords are used.

As your comments seem to be meant to be on separate lines, I'd prefix them with `\Statex` keywords.

Here the corrected MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm for finding server indices using OFG}

  \begin{algorithmic}
    \Statex \Comment { \%comment: servers[] contains the index of servers whose         data rate are sorted in descending order\%}
    \State servers[]= index(of all servers) 
    \State serverIndex[]=servers[0..K]
    \State linearlyIndependentServerIndex[]=0
    \State $[Z] \leftarrow 0$
    \For  {$i=0$ to $serverIndex.length$} 
    \Statex\Comment{ \%comment: find the equation corresponding the serverIndex        from the mapping at the File Server\%} 
    \State        $eqn= equation(serverIndex[i])$ 
    \Statex\Comment{ \%comment: try insert equation into Z using OFG\%} 

    \EndFor end for 
    \While{ ( linearlyIndependentServerIndex.length!=K ) } 
    \Statex\Comment{\%comment: remove all the server index which were not inserted in Z\%}  
    \State temp[]=serverIndex[]-linearlyIndependentServerIndex 
    \If{  (linearlyIndependentServerIndex.length=K) }
    \State break
    \EndIf  
    \EndWhile  
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks looks like i referred to a wrong doc which did not explain this properly.